# Reach a row containing email id of current user

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have email ID in Column B.

I want that the cursor must go to the row containing the email ID based on log in.

The below code when run from script editor works.

But, when the sheet opens, it does not work.

```
//
function onOpen() {
  var ordsht=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Order');
  var ordems=ordsht.getRange("B:B").getValues();
  var cem=Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  for (i=9;i<ordems.length;i++){
    if (ordems[i]==cem){
      ordsht.getRange("N"+(i+1)).activate();
    }
  }

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .createMenu('Options')
    .addSubMenu(SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Process')
      .addItem('Create fresh order sheet', 'make_order_sheet')
      .addItem('Open order sheet for feeding', 'open_order')
      .addItem('Close Order sheet for feeding', 'close_order')
      .addItem('Send customer order confirmation whatsapp', 'order_wup')
      .addItem('Send supplier purchase order whatsapp', 'supplier_order_wup')
      )
      .addSeparator()
      .addSubMenu(SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('From Slots Sheet')
          .addItem('Booked Whatsapp', 'send_wp_bk_slot_auto')
          )
      .addSeparator()
      .addItem('Wup from Any Sheet', 'send_any_wup')
      .addItem('Wup Campaign', 'mkt_campaign')
      .addToUi()
}
//
//
```

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getActiveUser()

tells me that

getActiveUser()
Gets information about the current user. If security policies do not allow access to the user's identity, User.getEmail() returns a blank string. The circumstances in which the email address is available vary: for example, the user's email address is not available in any context that allows a script to run without that user's authorization, like a simple onOpen(e) or onEdit(e) trigger, a custom function in Google Sheets, or a web app deployed to "execute as me" (that is, authorized by the developer instead of the user). However, these restrictions generally do not apply if the developer runs the script themselves or belongs to the same Google Workspace domain as the user.

Is there any way I can land on a particular row when a user opens the sheet? All users have edit rights.

My users are very old school and may not be comfortable "authorizing the script".

Answer (score 1):

If authorizing a script is a no-go then sadly no. As you have seen in the Google documentation, simple triggers lack the necessary authority to retrieve the user details. You would really need to have an installable trigger. You can write a rather simple function that when run will create an `onOpen` trigger for that script. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#newTrigger(String). The users would just have to run that function once from the menu option you add in the `onOpen()` function, which will prompt them to authorize the script. Then it should run every time properly.

Answer (score 0):

The below code works.

The user can jump to his row by clicking a menu option.

He can install a trigger to jump from the next time (requires authorization for both options)

```
function onOpen(e) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .createMenu('Options')
      .addItem('Jump to your row', 'jump_to_row')
      .addItem('Jump automatically from next time (click once only)', 'createSpreadsheetOpenTrigger')
      .addToUi()
}
//
function jump_to_row(){
  var ordsht=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Order');
  var ordems=ordsht.getRange("B:B").getValues();
  var cem=Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  for (i=9;i<ordems.length;i++){
    if (ordems[i]==cem){
      ordsht.getRange("N"+(i+1)).activate();
    }
  }
}
//
function createSpreadsheetOpenTrigger() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('jump_to_row')
      .forSpreadsheet(ss)
      .onOpen()
      .create();
}
//
```